# How do I call this method to main without changing it?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

For a homework assignment I have to print the smallest number not present in an array. This is my code so far:

```
public int mySolution(int[] arr) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int smallestNumber = 1;
    

    for(int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[0] != 1) {
            smallestNumber = 1;
        }
        else if((arr[i] + 1) != (arr[i+1])) {
            smallestNumber = arr[i] + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return smallestNumber;
    
    }
```

How do I call this method to main so I can print it without changing it? The mySolution method needs to stay as 'public int' for this homework so I am not sure how to call it in main. Thanks!

Comment: if the method isn't static (which I'd say this is an acceptable case for it),. then you need an instance of the object/class the method resides in.

Comment: `new YourClassName().mySolution(new int[] {0, 1, 3, 4, 5});`

Comment: The smallest int not in the array is the constant Integer.MIN_INT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate your class inside the `main` method like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    MyClass x = new MyClass();
    int[] exampleArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    System.out.println(x.mySolution(exampleArray));
}
```

You can then print what the method returns.

Keep in mind that `MyClass` is just a placeholder for what your class is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can create an Object from the class that contains the method and access your method.

```
public static void main(String []args)
     {
         int[] sample= {1,2,3};
         // Your class object
         TestClass t =new TestClass();
         System.out.print(t.mySolution(sample));
                   
     }
```

The other way is you can declare your method as a static method and access it without Object.
`public static int mySolution(int[] arr)`

```
public static void main(String []args)
         {
             int[] sample= {1,2,3};
             System.out.print(TestClass.mySolution(sample));
         }
```